# MVC popup\modal forms best practice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, crud

I am using MVC 3 and I am trying to find a good source that will list the best practices for using Modal dialog forms (jQuery or any other type)  and\or popup windows in my application.

For example:
I have my CRUD operation Views and their corresponding controller actions but i want the to be opened in a new window\modal dialog and when close to refresh the parent opener.

I can write a lot of ugly java script to implement that but I am looking for the best practice to incorporate that in an MVC application.

**Edits for certification of the question**

For modal dialogs Mainly I;m having trouble to understand how would all the client side validation work when the fields are loaded dynamically into a form container how would I remap the validation triggers...

For regular popup windows I don't wan to refresh the parent page and pass a parameter to select the newly created object..

so i can go both ways but I got stuck at different stages in both of them..

validation Any suggestions or links ?

Comment: modal dialog forms are client side stuffs, it is not so relevant what is running on the server. I don't think there is a best practice for modal dialogs. you may look for some jquery plugin, I'm sure there are a lot of plugin for this kind of problem. if you don't want to write ugly javascript then you should write nice and clean javascript code which is of course possible.  Btw, what is ASP.NET MVC 3.5? I know MVC 3 and 4 but never heard of 3.5 ;)

Comment: Hey.. sorry abut the 3.5 .. it's 3 .. i was confused .. :)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Twitter [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in one of my Asp.net MVC 4 projects. Twitter Bootstrap modal form is easier to use than normal javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice tutorial that uses jQuery:

**ASP MVC3 – Editing records with jQueryUI Dialogs and AjaxForms – Razor Version**

http://ricardocovo.com/2012/04/06/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms-razor-version/

**ASP MVC3 – Editing records with jQueryUI Dialogs and AjaxForms – ASPX Version**

http://ricardocovo.com/2011/04/03/asp-mvc3-editing-records-with-jqueryui-dialogs-and-ajaxforms/